# Common subroutines in RPM

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I have some common code that I would like to execute in the **%pre** and **%post** section of my **rpm** spec file.  When I place a subroutine in the **%pre** section, I need to add the same subroutine to the **%post** section of the RPM.  It sucks maintaining the same subroutine twice.  Here is an example:

**RPM** spec file **%pre** and **%post** sections:

```
%pre
log_file=/var/log/myrpminstall.log
#-------------------------------------
# Send text log_file
#-------------------------------------
log_it() {
  log_msg=$1
  echo -e $log_msg >> $log_file
}

log_it "pre section log information"

%post

log_it "Post section log informations"
```

Currently, when the **%post** section of the **rpm** executes during an install, I receive an error message:

```
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.36557: line 5: log_it: command not found
```

So, is there a way to make a subroutine like **log_it** accessible to all sections (global function) of the **RPM**??  Currently, I have to place the **log_it** function in the **%post** section if I want to use it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because each scriptlet (`%post`, `%pre`, etc.) is written as an independent script and passed to bash/sh for execution.  Thus the shell that executes it is unaware of any function defined in another scriptlet.

I'd recommend using RPM macros for this purpose.  You can put them in `~/.rpmmacros` or `/etc/rpm/macros`.  Something like this:

```
%define log \
log_it() { \
  log_msg=$1 \
  echo -e $log_msg >> $log_file \
}

%pre
%log

log_it test

%post
%log

log_it test
```

See http://rpm5.org/docs/rpm-guide.pdf for more info or even `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for..Works perfect now in %pre and %post...